# Agile Web development Creating a smarter cart errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New to Ruby on Rails, would appreciate if someone could help point me in the right direction. Thanks

```
Finished tests in 0.627036s, 38.2753 tests/s, 74.9558 assertions/s.



  1) Error:
CartsControllerTest#test_should_destroy_cart:
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template carts/destroy, application/destroy
 with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "c:/Users/Daniel Huang/My Documents/projects/trying-again/depot/app/views"

    app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:85:in `set_cart'
    test/controllers/carts_controller_test.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in <class:
    CartsControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/carts_controller_test.rb:43:in `block in <class:CartsControllerTest>'

  2) Error:
    CartsControllerTest#test_should_update_cart:
    ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template carts/update, application/update w
    ith {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby,
    :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
     * "c:/Users/Daniel Huang/My Documents/projects/trying-again/depot/app/views"

    app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:85:in `set_cart'
    test/controllers/carts_controller_test.rb:38:in `block in <class:CartsControllerTest>'

  3) Error:
    LineItemsControllerTest#test_should_create_line_item:
    AbstractController::ActionNotFound: The action 'create' could not be found for L
    ineItemsController
    test/controllers/line_items_controller_test.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in       <class:LineItemsControllerTest>'
     test/controllers/line_items_controller_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:LineIt
     emsControllerTest>'

  4) Error:
    LineItemsControllerTest#test_should_destroy_line_item:
    AbstractController::ActionNotFound: The action 'destroy' could not be found for
    LineItemsController
    test/controllers/line_items_controller_test.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in              class:LineItemsControllerTest>'
      test/controllers/line_items_controller_test.rb:43:in `block in     <class:LineItemsControllerTest>'

  5) Error:
      LineItemsControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
      ActionView::Template::Error: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
      app/views/line_items/_form.html.erb:1:in_app_views_line_items__form_html_erb___607916578_29103084'
    app/views/line_items/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_line_items_new_html_erb__
     _811078298_42530004'
    test/controllers/line_items_controller_test.rb:15:in `block in <class:LineIt
     emsControllerTest>'

  6) Error:
     LineItemsControllerTest#test_should_update_line_item:
     ActionController::ParameterMissing: param not found: line_item
    app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:89:in `line_item_params'
    app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:59:in `block in update'
    app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:58:in `update'
    test/controllers/line_items_controller_test.rb:38:in `block   in<class:LineItemsControllerTest>'

24 tests, 47 assertions, 0 failures, 6 errors, 0 skips

     c:\Users\Daniel Huang\My Documents\projects\trying-again\depot>
```

Comment: So, I know it's been 3 months since you asked this (so you've probably solved this already), but I should explain why you garnered basically no answers on this question. In general, when asking for help - you need to prove that you've at least *tried* to solve this yourself. so you should explain to us things like: what you tried, why it failed. What you were expecting the output to be.

Comment: Also - there's no use showing us the failing tests, without also showing us the code that should be making the tests pass. Finally: you didn't actually tell us which part was going wrong for you, and which part you most wanted help on.

Comment: You just dumped a bunch of failing test-output and said "go fix it for me" - ask yourself honestly - if somebody did that to you... and asked you for help - would you feel like helping them? Be nice to the people who are helping you  they are giving their time for free to  a stranger (ie you)... so be polite. Ask for help - explain what you need help with, show us that you've tried yourself.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply and suggestions I will keep them in mind next time I ask a question.

At the time when I posted the question I had been an absolute beginner and so I didn't even really know what had happened, all I saw was errors and freaked out.

Comment: Fair enough... but it's a general part of asking question that you provide as much information as you can to the people who will help you :)